# remove class on click other element in filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a filter with jQuery and it works great, I also add a class to the button onclick but I want the class to be removed when clicking on another button (currently it adds the class everywhere).

```js
$(function() {
  $(".filter-name").click(function() {

    selectedClass = $(this).attr("data-rel");
    $(".filter-content div").not("." + selectedClass).hide();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");

    setTimeout(function() {
      $("." + selectedClass).show();
    });

  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filters">
  <button class="filter-name" data-rel="all">All</button>
  <button class="filter-name" data-rel="a">A</button>
  <button class="filter-name" data-rel="b">B</button>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div class="filter-content">
    <div class="all a">a</div>
    <div class="all b">b</div>
    <div class="all a">a</div>
    <div class="all a">a</div>
    <div class="all b">b</div>
    <div class="all a">a</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason for selectedClass to be declared outside of the click handler?

Comment: You add a class on click, but nothing removes it in a way that makes sense. Because your buttons aren't toggles, toggleClass doesn't make sense here. Add the class to the clicked filter, remove it from all others.